# Hide a decimal using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

I have seen lot of questions but none of them seems to have answer for this. I need this help desperately. I am hosted on Magentogo so have no acceess to the core files, however with the help of jquery I want to hide .00 from my store. My codes look like this for example. The price of the item of Rs. is also in HTML could not paste as

```
              <div class="price-block"
              <p> The price of this item is 
                <span class="price" id="oldprice">
                     <span class="WebRupee"> Rs. </span>3,795.00             </span></p>
              </span>

                </div>

                <script>

                     $('#price-block').html($('#price-block').html().replace(".00",""));

                </script>

            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: Syntax Error... `<div class="price-block"` doesn't have an ending `>`
`

Comment: `Math.round(123.456);` // 123

Comment: And your have an extra span tag.

Comment: This would be much simpler if your price was wrapped in its own `<span>` tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have it as a class in your div

```
<div class="price-block" // <-- also missing >
```

use the class selector `.`

```
$('.price-block')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WBsjA/

Comment: Man you are truely genious, however I am embarassed at my limitation so asking you again. Basis what you had adviced, I made it work on jsfiddle however when I am applying at the server, it is not working. on JSfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/sanjoyforever/C9tDT/. Example on server. http://test[dot]gotossle[dot]com/index.html (this one is not working)

Comment: @Sanjoy are you copying straight from the fiddle? if so check to make sure you don't have invalid characters by copying and pasting to notepad++ first.  Usually theres a `?` at the end of the code.

Comment: See here `.replace(".00", ""));?` <-- when copied from jsfiddle and pasted in notepad++.. You just need to delete that question mark.. or whatever shows up depending on what you have the encoding set up as

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach. Since your price isn't wrapped in its own unique HTML `<span>` to make it easy to locate and replace, you need to parse the parent element, separate the child nodes from the text nodes, and rebuild it:

```
var newval;    
$('.price').each(function(j, pr) {
    // trick to remove the webRupee element for later
    var $webRupee = $(pr).find('.WebRupee').remove().wrap('<div>').parent().html();
    $(pr).contents().each(function(i, el) {
        if (el.nodeType === 3 && el.nodeValue.match(/\.00/)) {
           newval = el.nodeValue.replace(/\.00/, '');
        }
    });
    $(pr).html($webRupee + newval);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/r2V6r/

Comment: Also a good solution, but was not able to make it work on magentogo. :(

Comment: My code works perfectly, if you replace the `.000` in your original test code with the `.00` you actually have on your server. I've updated my answer (and your question).

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to loop each `.price-block` rather than trying to run it on the whole code mat once.

```
$('.price-block').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(".000","").replace(".00","").replace(".0",""));
});
```

Also you need to fix up your HTML markup

```
<div class="price-block">
    <p> The price of this item is 
        <span class="price" id="oldprice">
             <span class="WebRupee"> Rs. 3,795.000</span>
        </span>
    </p>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/XK48G/